# How do I run picam?

Tags: camera, raspicam, libcamera

I am trying to use picam on Raspi 5 with an atteched camera module and I get the following error:

`/home/myUser/picam/picam: error while loading shared libraries: libcamera.so.0.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have followed the install guide at https://github.com/iizukanao/picam/?ref=kamranicus.com#installation and I am using the latest release (2.0.12) with my raspi running the latest Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) with the codename bookworm.

Is there anything I can do?